# pytesseract OCR error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using `pytesseract` to get the text from the image. But I am getting this error.

This is my source file. The `dir` includes the image

```
import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
print image_to_string(Image.open('download.png'))
#download.png is in same dir as the source file is
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "ocr.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(image_to_string(Image.open('download.png')))

File "/home/suraj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
    config=config)

  File "/home/suraj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How to remove this error?

Comment: Have you installed tesseract-ocr package?

Comment: @max Yeah I didn;t installed tesseract-ocr-package on my machine..now working. Thanks

Comment: I'm very glad  to hear this. Also, it will be appreciated very much if you find a comment or an answer useful another time then you might upvote it.